# Provide default bookmark text for mobile devices

Tags: android, html, iphone

We can easily provide custom icons for bookmarks that will be used on mobile devices in HTML:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path-to-image/image.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<!-- manifest.json -->
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Full App Name",
    "version": "38",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "description": "App description",
    "short_name": "Short App Name",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "path-to-image/image.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": 4.0
        }
    ],
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

However, this will only change the bookmark icon and not the text. The default text will be taken from the page's title tag. This is a problem, because generally title tags are highly optimized for search engines and are not good for bookmarks used by humans.

Is there a way to change default text for bookmarks (at least on mobile devices)?

Comment: I was going to ask just this. There _must_ be a way.